# Visual Studio 2022 not allowing to sign in with azure devops credentials

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Brand new laptop, fresh new install of VS professional 2022.

Trying to sign in and get an error.

I am able to clone the repository from devops, make changes and push.

However, cant run or build because the sign in for the nuget packages.

I can see this in Visual Studio

[image]

When I click to connect, it loads the pop up.

[image]

After a long while I get pop to select the account, I click on the account and it continue to display the loading icon till it fail.

[image]

The log shows the below.

[image]

Tried few things:

- removed the C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.IdentityService and restarted VS
- repair Visual Studio
- removed the credentials in credential manager
- restarted machine

Run out ideas, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and observed that Azure DevOps was encountering difficulties with IPv6 connections. While one potential solution is to disable IPv6, I chose to implement a workaround by fixing the IPv4 address in the machine's hosts file. Here's a step-by-step guide for Windows:

1. To obtain the correct IP address for `dev.azure.com`, you can use the `ping` command:

   ```bash
   ping -4 dev.azure.com
   ```
2. Next, navigate to the hosts file located at `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc` and insert the following line, along with the IP address you obtained in the previous step:

   ```
   13.107.42.20 dev.azure.com
   ```

It's crucial to be aware that the IP address may change in the future, so you should periodically check and update your hosts file accordingly.